# Is there any nonlinear equations depending on Fourier coefficients?

Tags: fourier-transform, non-linear-systems

A nonlinear partial differential equation is an expression depending on derivatives of $u$
$$f(x,t,u,u_x,u_t,\cdots)=0,$$ 
where the derivatives of $u$ can be obtained from the Taylor series of $u$.

There is another expansion of $u$, that is the Fourier expansion, and the Fourier transform can be used in linear partial differential equations.

Now, my question is:

> Is there any nonlinear equation depending on Fourier coefficients?

These nonlinear equations are not derived from Fourier transform of linear equations, but from the real physics setting.